# Form handlig with variable elements

Tags: asp-classic

I have an html form that has to update contact data. But... each contact has a number of cars with related information viewed as table rows with input cells within the same form. Cars information has to be updated too. The number of cars for each person is not known in advance. How can I handle this in the Server with Request.Form;

Thanks

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>INFO1</td><td>INFO2</td><td>INFO3</td></tr>
    <%While Not rsVechicles.Eof%>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="VechicleID" value=<%=rsVechicles("VechicleID")%> /></td>
        <td><input name="info1" value=<%=rsVechicles("info1")%> /></td>
        <td><input name="info2" value=<%=rsVechicles("info2")%> /></td>
        <td><input name="info3" value=<%=rsVechicles("info3")%> /></td>
    </tr>
    <%rsVechicles.MoveNext%>
    <%Wend%>

</table>
```

Comment: For example: if a person has 3 vechicles then we have a collection of 3 items in Request.Form("VechicleID"):
Request.Form("VechicleID")(0)
Request.Form("VechicleID")(1)
Request.Form("VechicleID")(2)
The same for the other inputs (info1,info2,info3)
If each collection index corresponds to the same vehicle then it is ok. But is this true?

Comment: Sorry...not 0,1,2 but 1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some sort of counter variable to differentiate between the rows. Also, do you really mean for the user to be able to change the vehicle ID?

```vbs
<%
dim v
v = 0
%>
<form method="post" action="thispage.asp">
<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Info 1</th><th>Info 2</th><th>Info 3</th></tr>
<%
While Not rsVehicles.EOF
    v = v + 1
    Response.Write "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='ID_" & v & "'"
    Response.Write " value='" & rsVehicles("VehicleID") & "'>"
    Response.Write rsVehicles("VehicleID") & "</td>"
    For i = 1 to 3
        Response.Write "<td><input type='text' name='Info" & i & "_" & v & "'"
        Response.Write " value='" & rsVehicles("Info" & i) & "'></td>"
    Next
    Response.Write "</tr>"
    rsVehicles.Movenext
Wend
Response.Write "<input type='hidden' name='N' value='" & v & "'>"
%>
</table>
```

Then when you're reading values from the form, you can loop through the same indexes:

```vbs
v = Request.Form("N") '- number of vehicles
For i = 1 to v
    Vehicles(i,0) = Request.Form("ID_" & i)
    For j = 1 to 3
        Vehicles(i,j) = Request.Form("Info" & j & "_" & i)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: in form's code you did not use the i inside for next... something is wrong

Comment: @nonlinearly: oops, sorry, you're right. Fixed, now. (Stupid "changing your mind halfway through" types of errors...)

Comment: @nonlinearly If this answer helped, consider accepting it. Please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)